Swiper.js - не показывать промежуточные слайды при вызове slideTo
Если скролить к определенному слайду, то промежуточные тоже промелькнут https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/x6fsff?file=%2Findex.html
Например если перейти с первого сразу к девятому, то 2-8 тоже промелькнут. Мне же нужно, чтобы была анимация слайдера, как будто слайды находятся рядом

Может этот метод - slideToClickedSlide: true, вставить? Я не проверял если что.

Минимум усилий - это если изменить дефолтный transition-duration у Swiper. Сделать поменьше. Проверил в хроме и файерфоксе выглядит как будто они рядом
.swiper-wrapper { transition-duration: 120ms !important;}

Этот вариант очень кривой. Время анимации теперь не задать, но при этом промежуточные слайды все равно мелькают. Тут уже лучшее вообще отказаться от анимации
